# VS2013 Application Insight for desktop applications

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-application-insights

I have created one desktop application using MFC. It contains different tabs like settings, about etc. I want to know hit count of these tabs i.e. how many times user clicks/opens these tabs. Can I use Application Insights or is there any other method to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature, it seems, is quite wanted and you can vote for it on the official site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5484795-add-support-for-desktop-apps-to-application-insigh.

I also agree this will be awesome if they make it available for desktop applications, so fingers crossed!

**edit:** As it seems, on the upper link I provided, on December 05, 2014 they added support for this in the following matter:

> While desktop apps are not listed as targeted app types for Application Insights, it’s possible to get instrumentation for desktop apps using Application Insights SDK. Please refer to this thread for more details: [Application Insights for WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505483/appinsights-for-wpf-application/26641583#26641583). At this point Application Insights team believes this should unblock most of the users who voted for this feature, and we are closing this item and releasing your votes back to you. Please let us know if there is another aspect that blocks using AppInsights for desktop apps.

Answer (score 2):

To get started though, from SDK perspective we can support other types of apps like desktop apps. Here are the steps required to setup it up manually and the code required to get metrics, events, traces, etc sent to the application insights service.

[Desktop App with App Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505483/appinsights-for-wpf-application/26641583#26641583)