# Application Insights for WPF Application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

There is a WPF application written in Visual Studio.
Can I add Application Insights to this WPF app?
I would like to know how many times a button/tile is clicked. Since there are multiple installations
of the same application, I would like to know which button was clicked how many times from which user/installation. Can this be done with Application Insights?

Thanks
Avanti

Comment: @Sinatr How are you going to get those logs from your client to you? And what if you have a million clients, are you going to open a million csv files in excel? Take a look at AI analytics, it is a whole nother level: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-analytics/

Answer (score 31):

While not listed as a supported app type this means there isn't default telemetry data collected/sent to application insights nor is there support for adding AI/creating an application insights resource.  That being said it is possible to add to your WPF with a few manual steps so that you can track the specific scenarios you mention (like a button/tile click).

-From Visual studio add the "Application Insights API" NuGet to the project (.11 is the latest today).

This will add the Application Insights API reference and create an application insights configuration file to your project.

The applicationinsights.config file needs to be updated with your instrumentation key as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" schemaVersion="2014-05-30">
    <TelemetryChannel>
        <DeveloperMode>false</DeveloperMode>
    </TelemetryChannel>
    <TelemetryModules>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
    </TelemetryModules>
    <InstrumentationKey>**your-instrumentation-key-guid**</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

To create an application insights instrumentation key login to your azure subscription.
https://portal.azure.com
Click + to create an Application Insights resource. 
Then choose the properties tile on the application insights blade and copy the Instrumentation key and add it to your applicationinsights.config file.
Now in your WPF app you can use the Application Insights sdk as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/10/21/application-insights-sdk-0-11-0-prerelease.aspx

your events will be visible in the diagnostic search blade which can be selected on the application insights blade.

Note: telemetry is batched locally for 1 min before being sent to the service unless > 500 telemetry events are queued at which point they are sent.

Comment: What about batched event when the app is closed ? Are Exceptions batched or sent immediately ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it got me just far enough for me to figure out the rest I needed to know.

Answer (score 15):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/

An official link from Microsoft on how to add Application Insights to a Windows Forms application.  From the link:

In Azure - portal.azure.com

1. Create an Application Resource. ::New / Developer Services / Application Insights.
2. Notice the instrumentation key generated, grab a copy and set it aside, we'll need it when we configure your application.

In Your Application

1. NuGet - Add 'Application Insights API'
2. Configure your `TelemetryClient`.

I'm using MvvmCross in a WPF application, on startup I create a single `TelemetryClient` that I re-use throughout the application.

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = "your key here from Azure";
telemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
telemetryClient.Context.User.AccountId = Username;
telemetryClient.Context.Component.Version = Settings.Default.Version; 
telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Application Start");
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<TelemetryClient>(telemetryClient);
```

3. Record an event/screen/exception, etc

Any time 'something happens' I'll resolve the `TelemetryClient` and record the event.  This is just like any other Application Insights implementation with regards to tracking and recording.

As an example -

```
//Resolve the telemetry client
readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = Mvx.Resolve<TelemetryClient>();

//Record a page View with some extra information
var pageviewTelemetry = new PageViewTelemetry("Observations");
pageviewTelemetry.Properties.Add("Breadcrumb", breadcrumb);
telemetryClient.TrackPageView(pageviewTelemetry);

//Track an event
var eventTelemetry = new EventTelemetry("Observation Saved");            
eventTelemetry.Properties.Add("Saved Observation", observation);
telemetryClient.TrackEvent(eventTelemetry);

//Track an exception
try
{
  // do work here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    telemeteryClient.TrackException(ex);
}
```

4. Flush on Application Exit

Application Insights for Windows Desktop applications does not automatically gather/send anything.  As a developer one needs to force a flush at application exit.

```
private void PowerButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tc = Mvx.Resolve<TelemetryClient>();
    if (null != tc)
    {
        tc.Flush(); // only for desktop apps
    }            
    Application.Current.Shutdown();            
}
```

Or setup an RxTimer to flush on a schedule...I decided to flush every 30 minutes:

```
var observable = Observable.Interval(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0));
observable.Subscribe(_ =>  Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    var tc = Mvx.Resolve<TelemetryClient>();
    if (null != tc)
    {
        tc.Flush(); // only for desktop apps
        Console.WriteLine("Flush TC");
    }
})));
```

FYI - As of 0.17.0 of the Application Insights API NuGet Package if you are offline the flush call doesn't hang, but appears to.  Online, the call completes immediately, offline there is a solid 5 second pause before the call completes.

Comment: Your note about AI not automatically sending events conflicts with the accepted answer (written by an MS eployee who apparantly works in the AI team): *telemetry is batched locally for 1 min before being sent to the service unless > 500 telemetry events are queued at which point they are sent*. So I'm guessing the timer you set is unnecessary, and flushing on application exit should be enough.

Comment: @Vadim Can you help me to register it on Prism?

Answer (score 5):

Application Insights (AI) for desktop applications is being deprecated in favor of [HockeyApp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.WPF/). It's not overly mature yet, but it works (events essentially reach the same place AI events go).

For example, here's how it looks in [RoslynPad](https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad/blob/367757d5b19896c97671766218160a986fb6d503/src/RoslynPad/MainViewModel.cs) (a WPF C# Editor):

```
using Microsoft.HockeyApp;


//In your initialization method:
var hockeyClient = (HockeyClient)HockeyClient.Current;

hockeyClient.Configure(HockeyAppId)
    .RegisterCustomDispatcherUnhandledExceptionLogic(OnUnhandledDispatcherException)
    .UnregisterDefaultUnobservedTaskExceptionHandler();

var platformHelper = (HockeyPlatformHelperWPF)hockeyClient.PlatformHelper;
platformHelper.AppVersion = _currentVersion.ToString();

hockeyClient.TrackEvent("App Start");

//sometime later:
hockeyClient.TrackEvent("Something happened");
```

**EDIT** Looks like the following NuGet package is required in order for this to work properly: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HockeySDK.WPF.TelemetryWorkaround (see https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Windows/pull/88).

Comment: @MicheleFerracin you can still use the package, it just doesn't appear in search results. The author removed it because it was a hacky solution and he moved to using AI directly in RP (you can check out his code on GitHub or see the answers above).

Comment: Just been to look at HockeyApp, it says "HockeyApp was retired and the SDKs are deprecated. Please use App Center instead."