# Azure webforms application insights

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

Is it possible use Visual Studio 2013 Application Insights with my web forms project?

I have added application insight to my project but cannot get performance metrics to Application Insights portal. My project is running top of Azure web sites.

Answer (score 2):

There's now an Azure Websites Extension that supports perf metrics for azure websites:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-and-azure-websites.aspx

> If you have an Azure WebSite and would like to enable Application
>   Insights follow these steps:
>
> 1) Onboard your application to Application Insights from Visual Studio
>   2013 Update 3 or later and deploy to an Azure WebSite.
>
> Note:  If your application onboarded to Application Insights already
>   ensure you are using the .12 SDK (or later).
>
> 2) Enable the Application Insights Extension on the Azure WebSite
>   blade (not the Application Insight blade) for the website that was
>   enabled for Application Insights with the .12 or later SDKs
>
> 3) Now the extension is enabled execute a few requests against your
>   web App and navigate to your Application Insights resource blade

Comment: Your mentioned extension just helps to collect some dependencies data. Performance counters (CPU, memory, disc I/O) are not supported in Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Application Insights will only work with Web Applications.

Here are the project types supported:

1. A web service or web application.
2. Web pages that use JavaScript. A
3. Windows Phone 8 app.
4. A Windows Store app.

See this page for further information on the types of projects you can monitor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481095.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ken's answer is right for the types of apps that application insights supports really well.  this includes seamless onboarding/getting started and loads of "automatic" data visible without having to write any new lines of code.

From an SDK "core" perspective we can support other types of apps like WPF and desktop apps.  Here are the steps required to setup it up manually and the code required to get metrics, events, traces, etc sent to the application insights service.  this should just work if your winform app is running on an azure website too.

[Application Insights for WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505483/appinsights-for-wpf-application/26641583#26641583)

Comment: Vlad, you need to update this answer now that you've posted this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-and-azure-websites.aspx

Answer (score 0):

At the present time, **Application Insights is focused just on web-based applications**.

- ASP.NET Web Forms
- ASP.NET MVC
- ASP.NET Web API
- ASP.NET Core
- WCF
- JavaScript

and some alternative platforms / languages (PHP, Ruby, Java).

Azure App Service (formerly Web Sites) **does not support Performance Counters** (CPU percentage, Disc read/write operations, Available Memory etc.).

For clarification: Azure Website Extension just helps you to collect dependencies and some statistics in case your application is running on .NET version < 4.6.