# Application insights track metric is not working?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I followed up this question: [Application insights for wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505483/application-insights-for-wpf-application%20%22Application%20insights%20for%20wpf%20application) and created console application, where I am using application insights like this:

```
var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
telemetry.TrackEvent("My event");
telemetry.TrackMetric("Test Metric", 13);
telemetry.TrackTrace("Simple log message");
telemetry.TrackException(new Exception());
```

Everything works and data is sent to Azure, except TrackMetric. Metric is not available neither in metrics explorer, neither in diagnostic statistics.

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Same problem. I'm tracking from a worker role application, no metrics can be found in the metrics explorer..

Comment: @PeterLindström I use workaround with custom events with properties and metrics. Still, it's not possible to vizualise this data. All you can do, is to go inside each event to see these values. If no one will post better answer, will submit it by myself with custom events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2/5/15**: Custom metrics exposed through `trackMetric` and the various `trackEvent( x, properties, metrics )`, or other `track` calls that take custom properties and metrics should now be visible in both Metrics Explorer and event details blades.

**Prior**: metrics were only visible in event detail property blades (at the bottom)

Comment: Thank you. What about displaying names of these custom properties in Azure portal? Refering to my question in your [github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/issues/2529)

Comment: A deployment yesterday corrected display of custom property/metric names.   I'm still checking to see if yesterday's deployment also enabled trackMetric, but i'm *pretty* sure it did not.

Answer (score 0):

@PeterLindström, @Tonven
You should be able to now visualize data for custom metrics and properties. [Go to this blog to learn more](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/02/07/metrics-explorer-custom-metrics-and-events.aspx)