# Can't see metrics on Azure sent by AppInsights-Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a Rails application and I want to start tracking some metrics and events.
I must track this information using Microsoft Azure, so I found a the gem [AppInsights-Ruby](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppInsights-Ruby) developed by Microsoft itself.

I got my `instrumentation_key` and did what the README says but I can't see any information on the Azure portal.

I thought it could be a problem with the queues so I filled up the queue with

```
2000.times {|x| tc.track_metric 'My metric', x }
6000.times {|x| tc.track_event 'My event' }
```

But again, there is no metrics or events on the Azure portal.

Does anybody used this gem?
Am I missing something?

Comment: while not an exact duplicate, (different language) this is a very similar issue, where to see metrics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294308/application-insights-track-metric-is-not-working

Comment: Actually the issue is not _where to see them_. It is why they are not accepted.
I found that I got a 400 response with `Not a valid JSON object` body, that is weird because it is generated by the gem and it is a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is potentially a JSON issue in `v0.3.0` of this gem. After investigating we saw that the return information from the API said our JSON was invalid (but the JSON was created by the gem.)

`v0.5.0` changes how it uses JSON and that seemed to have resolved the issue.

The `v0.5.0` changes [are here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppInsights-Ruby/blob/master/lib/application_insights/channel/sender_base.rb#L46-L49)

Answer (score 0):

where are you looking for them?

when you use `track_metric`, the metrics by themselves don't show up as "events", you have to use `track_event` (or others) to send events.

metrics like this should, though, show up in metrics explorer.  (open your overview page, find the "metrics explorer" part, click it, and then in the edit blade scroll to the bottom, there should be a "Custom Metrics" section, and your metrics should show up there.

If you attach the metrics in a `track_[event|pageview|request|exception|trace]`, then you'll see those events in the diagnostic search list and the metrics will appear as event properties, in the properties blade.

If you don't see them at all on the portal, try using something like fiddler to watch the outbound requests, and see if you see data going to dc.services.visualstudio.com, where the data is collected.  Those requests/responses should indicate if data is successfully being transmitted.

Comment: I am looking for any kind of metric|event|exception|etc on the `Diagnose search` blade, and all the graphs but nothing happens.
I will try with the `fiddler` gem to see what is going on.
BTW I'm using the gem from the `irb console`.

Comment: like i said, `track_metric` won't generate anything that shows on the diagnostic search blade, as the calls aren't tracked as an individual event. (you'll only see things from `track_event`, etc, there).  try looking in metrics explorer, you should see them in the custom section of the configuration there.

Comment: I tried with the `track_event` and also looked on the metrics explorer. There is nothing there :/

Comment: Thanks for the help John — posted some more info that might be helpful