# Custom metric telemetry doesn't appear in the Metric Browser of Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm using a `TelemetryClient` class to send different types of telemetry (from my WPF app), but I have a problem with `MetricTelemetry`... all other types of telemetry work fine, but my `MetricTelemetry` custom data doesn't appear in the Metric Browser - Custom...

I call for example `telemetryClient.TrackMetric("MyMetric", 1)`, then go to the Azure portal, but custom metrics still contains only "Azure Diag issues" field

Comment: You might want to use Fiddler and check if data is actually accepted. If you see 206 response code check response content.

Comment: I found the metrics as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28333925/1229323)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, it helped doing two things:

- Call `Flush()` on the telemtryClient after sending the message
- Logged in to Azure using inccognito mode, to away cached items

Answer (score -1):

Dominik, does the problem still exist? Sometimes you might see a ~5-10 mins delay in time between you run the code to track metric and the metric shows up in the portal.

Comment: still not working... I created also App Insights on different Azure account, but same problem