# Azure function is not logging custom events to application insights

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have created a Service bus triggered Azure function and want to log custom events in application insights.

```
 private static string key = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey =
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
                "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        private static TelemetryClient telemetryClient =
            new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = key };

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("xxxxx", "xxxxx", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "SBConnectionKey")]string mySbMsg, ILogger logger, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

            telemetryClient.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "AIFunction";
            logger.LogMetric("test", 123);

            telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Ack123 Recieved");
            telemetryClient.TrackMetric("Test Metric", DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
       }
```

I can see only `log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");`this logs in the trace. But custom events and metrics are not logging to application insights.
Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: first thing I would verify is that you're getting the instrumentation key you expect.  that it is both (1) set and (2) sending telemetry to the resource you *think* it is.

Answer (score 4):

Answering your explicit question:

*What is wrong with the telemetry that I send or where to find it in Application Insights Portal?*

I created the function with almost the same code and tested. You can analyse the [repo](https://github.com/pharrukh/how-to-use-app-insights). I deployed the function and got the following results:

[image: Event found through query]

[image: Metric found through query]

Answering your implicit question:

*How to use Application Insights?*

It is tricky at the beginning to use App Insights query language, I found [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/A/C/4AC8A5BF-562D-4B7B-A261-337716044F14/SQL%20cheat%20sheet.pdf) succinct file helpful. Other elements to consider in working with this monitoring tool:

1. there is a lagging between the telemetry is sent and you see it in application insights portal. Real time monitoring would be an expensive tool.
2. In the past I faced the same issue and the problem was that event/metric name was not found in the name of the telemetry but somewhere in details. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294308/application-insights-track-metric-is-not-working) issue, might be referring to it. So what we decided to do is put more details and use of [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/91e9c91fcea979b1eec4e31ba8e0fc683bf86802/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/TelemetryClient.cs#L249) method and [MetricTelemetry](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/8673ed1d15005713755e0bb9594acfe0ee00b869/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/DataContracts/MetricTelemetry.cs) class.
3. Although Application Insights might seem confusing, that is a powerful tool, it is worth investing time to learn better.

Comment: Hi Farrukh Normuradov, Thanks for the detailed answer. Appreciate your efforts. But you have used HttpTrigger. I see it is working with that, but not with ServiceBusTrigger. Is there anything additional we have to add for ServiceBusTrigger to make it work. Thansk

Comment: @CGN007, I tested it with Service Bus Queue trigger. I added the code to the [repo](https://github.com/pharrukh/how-to-use-app-insights).

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s71i1hpnno7fstl/Screen%20Shot%202018-09-01%20at%201.33.30%20AM.png?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eunx4lubagweh6k/Screen%20Shot%202018-09-01%20at%201.33.40%20AM.png?dl=0) you can find the result.

I can confirm that it works. Just deploy my function app and test it.

Comment: @CGN007 did you have a chance to try what I prepared for you?