# Logging to Azure Cloud from a desktop WPF application

Tags: wpf, azure, logging

I have a WPF desktop application which currently outputs diagnostic logs using NLog to a local file system. I would like to have the option of putting those logs on the Azure cloud in some kind of logical storage system.

Can someone point me to to resources for this?  I found this link, but not quite sure if this is the way to go, using a BLOB storage container.  Is there a big cost associated with this?   The logs will be pretty sparse. i cannot see more than a few KB per day per workstation in terms of log storage. This is just text information, such as errors, key events, etc.

I found this link, but need to make sure it is applicable to what I'm trying to do:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet

Thanks
Mike

Comment: How hard did you search? "Nlog to cloud" got  bunch of hits via google. Second on the list  https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-cloud-logging-with-Azure-function-or-AWS-lambda

Answer (score 0):

Blob storage is really cheap if you are not using much. You are probably looking at pennies a day.

For the instrumentation consider using Application Insights.

See this SO answer: [Application Insights for WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505483/application-insights-for-wpf-application)