# Application Insights Sampling for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-application-insights, sampling

I want to know about the sampling options available for a WPF application (.Net v4.6.2). From what I could understand from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling), for scenarios such as this, only `Ingestion Sampling` is allowed as the other sampling options can't be applied using the Application Insights SDK (v2.6.4). So is my understanding correct about `Adaptive Sampling` and `Fixed-Rate Sampling` in relation to a WPF application? If not, how can I set them at the SDK level.

Comment: Documentation is very confusing.  this is my interpretation of the sampling.  You have an input queue and sampling is looking at the pointers in the queue to see if it is reaching the max limits.  So there are three options 1) Adaptive Sampling : Process a percentage of samples and Throw away samples is you are reaching the max size of queue. 2) Ingestion Sampling : Attempt to process a percentage of samples, but if you are reaching the limits of the queue stop processing the current sample and move on to next. 3) Fixed-Rate Sampling : Sample a percentage of inputs and do not check limits.

Comment: @jdweng - Thank you for summarizing the concepts here, but I am having a hard time understanding the documentation..almost all the examples I have seen are in relation to .Net Core that too in a web application scenario...

Comment: I've been having the same issue with Microsoft Documentation for 40 years.  Microsoft documentation is designed for 8th Grade reading level.  So the number of pages, number of paragraphs per page, number of sentences per paragraph, number of words per sentence are all limited. Plus the words have to be in an 8th grade dictionary.

Comment: You would be writing the data explicitly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505483/application-insights-for-wpf-application

Comment: @Andy I have that part working for me. So, you are saying in such a case, the Sampling will not come in picture and everything will be sent from the SDK level..is that correct?.

Comment: Once you have the data in there, then it doesn't matter where it came from. The challenge is getting the data there since it's you writing code that makes that happen. In asp.net it's automagic and the request pipeline handles it for you. There is no wpf equivalent. All the data input is from code you write. The outputs are then whatever it can do based on that. Of this data, some is free, most costs.

Comment: @gkb, please refer to the answer below. If it's helpful, please accept it as answer. And if you still have issues, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For non-web project, you can consider using [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#supported-scenarios) for adaptive / fixed-rate sampling.

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#using-applicationinsightsserviceoptions) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#sampling) section for more details.